# Selecting an element by class in JSoup

Tags: jsoup

I have the following HTML, I want to be able to extract the name and number of cars from the fragment using JSoup

```
<div class="user-info clearfix">
    <div class="user-review-name clearfix">
        <a class="user-review-name-link" rel="nofollow" title="go to tom&#39;s profile">
            tom
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        2 cars
    </div>
```

I can get the name ok, but I just can't get what is in the clearfix class. This is my code.

```
        Elements reviews = doc.select("div.review");
        for (Element review : reviews) {
            Elements subreviews = review.select("div.user-info");
            for (Element subreview : subreviews) {
                System.out.println(subreview.select("a.user-review-name-link").text());
                System.out.println(subreview.select("div:not(.user-review-name-link)").text());
            }
        }
```

I have tried different combinations, but for some reason I can never get **2 cars** by itself. Help?

```
System.out.println(subreview.select("div.clearfix").text());
```

I would have thought this would work too, but it produces this format "tom 2 cars tom 2 cars"

Comment: After fiddling, I just ended up asking for the text within the 3rd div element and it worked. ie review.select("div.clearfix").get(3).text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
final StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
Elements result = doc.select("div.clearfix");

    result.traverse(new NodeVisitor() {
        public void head(Node node, int depth) {
          // DEBUG:  System.out.println("Entering tag: " + node.nodeName());
            if(node instanceof TextNode) {
                buff.append(((TextNode) node).text());
            }
        }
        public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
            //Nothing to see here
        }
    });
```

then print content of buff here.